# Creating a new object seems change another object previously created (???)

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have a probem with a class I'm writing. 
It consists in a Matrix represented as an std::array of std::array. So the first array is a sort of container of columns or rows (this can be decided by the user).
The class keeps trave of this by using a boolean.

When I create a single instance of that all seems ok, the problem appears when i create an another instance: the second instance is ok, while in the first the boolean value changes.
I can't figure out the reason of this behaviour.

The problem is present only if i put the initializeToZero() method inside the default constructor, or also with the copy constructor. Moreover the 2 instance must have the same numberOfColumn, otherwise the problem does not appear.

I link you the most relevant part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <typename scalar,int numberOfRows,int numberOfColumns> class FullArrayMatrix {
     bool onlyColumnBased; //if true the first array contains the columns

     array<array<scalar, numberOfRows>, numberOfColumns> verticalMatrixArray;
     array<array<scalar, numberOfColumns>, numberOfRows> horizontalMatrixArray;
     // if onlyColumnBased is true tre programm considers only verticalMatrixArry, if false only horizontalMatrixArray

public:
///CONSTRUCTOR
    FullArrayMatrix (bool forceColumnBased=true):onlyColumnBased(forceColumnBased){
         initializeToZero();
    } //default initializer


    bool getOnlyColumnBased() const;
    void print();


    ///OPERATOR
    scalar & operator ()(int riga, int colonna);
};

//initializeToZero

template <typename scalar,int numberOfRows,int numberOfColumns>
void FullArrayMatrix<scalar,numberOfRows,numberOfColumns>::initializeToZero() {
    for (int i=1; i<=numberOfRows; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=numberOfColumns; j++) {
            if ((*this)(i,j)) {
                (*this)(i,j)=0;
            }
        }
    }

}

//print

template<typename scalar,int numberOfRows,int numberOfColumns> void FullArrayMatrix<scalar, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns >::print(){
    cout<<endl<<"--"<<endl;


    if (getOnlyColumnBased()) {
        for (int i=1; i< numberOfRows+1; i++) {
            cout<<"|\t";
            for (int j=1; j< numberOfColumns+1; j++) {
                cout<<(*this)(i,j)<<"\t";
            }
            cout<<"|"<<endl;
        }
    }

    else {
        for (int i=1; i< numberOfColumns+1; i++) {
            cout<<"|\t";
            for (int j=1; j< numberOfRows+1; j++) {
            cout<<(*this)(i,j)<<"\t";
            }
            cout<<"|"<<endl;
        }
    }
   cout<<"--"<<endl;

}


template <typename scalar,int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns> scalar & FullArrayMatrix<scalar,numeroRighe,numeroColonne>::operator ()(int row, int column){
    if (getOnlyColumnBased()) {
        return verticalMatrixArray[column][row];
    } else {
        return horizontalMatrixArray[row][column];
    }

}
```

This is the main:

```
FullArrayMatrix<double, 10, 1> full1(true);
full1.print();

cout<<full1.getOnlyColumnBased()<<endl;
FullArrayMatrix<double, 10, 1> full2(true);

cout<<endl<<endl<<full1.getOnlyColumnBased()<<full2.getOnlyColumnBased()<<endl;

full1.print();

full1.initializeToZero();
full1.print();
```

And this is the output:

```
--
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
--
1


01

--
|   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.49057e-320    |
--

--
|   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   |
--
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Are you really sure about your indexing conditions in the `for()` loops: `for (int i=1; i< numberOfRows+1; i++)`? Shouldn't this be `for (int i=0; i< numberOfRows; i++)`?

Comment: Error #1 found! Yes, you're right, this part of code is right because i need to acccess element in matrix starting from 0, not from 1, but I write a wrong overloaded operator() method: I have to put [column-1][row-1] and so on. Now the number 3.49057e-320 does not apper, but using the copy constructor the value of the boolean also changes..

Comment: Why don't you have `onlyColumnBased` a template parameter? It could be the last template parameter with default value. Changing the value of `onlyColumnBased` for an existing object seems really weird -- and there is no other need for that data member.

Comment: In my idea `onlyColumnBased` might be important to traspose the matrix, I can simply swap `verticalMatrixArray` and `horizontalMatrixArray` and change the value of `onlyColumnBased`. Do you think this is not a good thing to do?

Comment: Solved..I simply exchanged 2 indexes..Excuse me for the problem, but I really wasn't able to solve it! Thank you for the time you took to reply me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first comment I discovered a stupid error, now the only problem is in the copy constructor. As described before it seems to change `onlyColumnBased` in the input matrix. 
How can it change this value? `inputMatrix` is a const reference, isn't it?

The code is the following:

In the declaration:

```
FullArrayMatrix (const FullArrayMatrix<scalar,numeroRighe,numeroColonne> &inputMatrix,bool forceColumnBased=true);
```

In the implementation:

```
template <typename scalar,int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns> FullArrayMatrix<scalar, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns >::FullArrayMatrix (const FullArrayMatrix<scalar, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns > &matriceInput,bool forceColumnBased):onlyColumnBased(forceColumnBased){
cout<<endl<<endl<<matriceInput.getOnlyColumnBased()<<onlyColumnBased;

    if (!onlyColumnBased) {
        for (int i=1; i< numberOfRows +1; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j< numberOfColumns +1; j++) {
                (*this)(i,j)=inputMatrix.horizontalMatrixArray[j-1][i-1];
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i=1; i< numberOfColumns +1; i++) {
            cout<<endl<<"column "<<i<<" "<<inputMatrix.getOnlyColumnBased();

            for (int j=1; j< numberOfRows +1; j++) {
                cout<<endl<<"row "<<j<<" "<<inputMatrix.getOnlyColumnBased();

                (*this)(i,j)=inputMatrix.verticalMatrixArray[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }

    }
    cout<<inputMatrix.getOnlyColumnBased();
}
```

I have put some `cout` to notice when `onlyColumnBased` changes and it seems to change in the 1st column, 3rd row.

This is the main:

```
FullArrayMatrix<double, 10, 1> full1(true);
full1.print();

FullArrayMatrix<double, 10, 1> full2(full1,true);
full1.print();
```

This is the output:

```
--
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
|   0   |
--


11

column 1 1
row 1 1
row 2 1
row 3 1
row 4 0
row 5 0
row 6 0
row 7 0
row 8 0
row 9 0
row 10 0

0
--
|   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   |
--
```

I really dont't have idea of the problem!

Comment: Solved..I simply exchanged 2 indexes..Excuse me for the stupid problem, but I really wasn't able to solve it!
Thank you for the time you took to reply me!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an off-by-one error ("there are two hard problems in computer science: naming things, cache coherency, and off-by-one errors"): C++ uses zero based arrays. You are accessing indices `1`...`numberOf...` in your `initializeToZero()` method. As a result you'll have a buffer overrun which, apparently, results in some of your variables being overwritten.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved a little problem as suggested in the first comment, but I have again an error in the copy constructor.. I write the code in the next answer!